# Wordpress - show posts from a particular category in sidebar "recent posts"

Tags: wordpress

how can i make the "recent posts" in the WP sidebar show posts from a particular category only?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Probably easiest to make your own recent posts widget with one of Otto's php code widgets http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/php-code-widget/  and a new query:

```
<?php $my_query = new WP_Query('category_name=mycategory&showposts=1'); ?>

<?php while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post(); ?>

<a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>">

<?php the_title(); ?></a>

<?php endwhile; ?>
```

Style it any way you want. The new query loop won't conflict with the main WP loop and can be used any numbers of time.

Answer (score 3):

Or if you prefer something a little more user-friendly(doesn't require posting code into the widget), you may find the following plugin of use.

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/query-posts/

Nice little plugin that one, written by Justin Tadlock.

Answer (score 0):

Just #FYI on both previous answers here: 
'Otto's php code widgets' was last updated more than two years ago and has not been tested on the last 3 major Wordpress releases. Justin Tadlock's plugin also hasn't been tested on the last 3 major Wordpress releases.

At time of writing this update the recommended plugin is '[Category Posts Widget](https://wordpress.org/plugins/category-posts/)' by TipTopCopy, which was last updated approximately 2 weeks ago.